# TikZ: non-linear tangent curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to draw a tangent curve from point `(a)` to point `(b)`, intersecting point `(c)` (the center of the square). The curve should be stretched according to the gray lines (being a logarithmic scale). I've played around with `controls`, but I didn't get very far. Is there a better way than using `controls`?

My code so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.01cm}]

\draw (0, 1) -- (10, 1) -- (10, -1) -- (0, -1) -- cycle;
\node (a) at (0, -1) {a};   % south-west corner
\node (b) at (10, 1) {b};   % north-east corner
\node (c) at (5, 0) {c};    % center
\foreach \n in {1,...,50} \draw[gray, very thin]
        ({10/pow(2, \n/12)}, 1)
    --  ({10/pow(2, \n/12)}, -1);

\draw[cyan] (a) -- (b);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

What I want to achieve is the following (although the left half of the curve should decrease more rapidly):
[image]

Comment: Among your trials, have you come across this `\draw (0,-1) .. controls (5,-1.0) and (5,1.0) .. (10,1);` Further, you could try (5,-1.1) and (5,1.1) pairs too.

Comment: The first thing I tried was `\draw[cyan] (a) .. controls (4, -1) and (6, 1) .. (b);`. But this obviously draws a linear curve - and I'd like to have it logarithmic.

Comment: I don't undersand the "logarithmic" nature of your curve. What is is supposed to increase logarithmically? The derivative of the curve? Then, how could it be tangent to (b)?

Comment: Will this produce what you want? `\draw[cyan] (a) to[out=0,in=180] (b);`

Comment: Or what about this: `\draw[cyan] (a) .. controls +(4, 0) and +(-.5, -.5) .. (c.center) .. controls +(.5,.5) and +(-2,0) .. (b);
` ?

Comment: Hi, watain, just a thought: Continue searching `\draw (0,-1) .. controls (6,-1.0) and (4,1.0) .. (10,1);`  (7,-1) and (3,1); (8,-1) and (2,1) or any pairs among them, should get one of your expected output.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Unfortunately I'm unable to explain what I exactly want, but all of your examples get pretty close to what I need. Maybe this explanation helps: take a curve like `\draw (a) .. controls (6, -1) and (4, 1) .. (b);`, then _squeeze_ the whole curve horizontally, squeezing the left side stronger than the right side. As a result, the left side curve will descent faster to the tangent through `(a)` as seen from the center `c`.

Comment: I would suggest finding a parametric model y=f(x) and solve for the parameters to fit your three points.  y=ax^2 + bx + c?  y=ax^b + c?  y = ax ln(x) + b ln(x) + c?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this comes some what closer?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.01cm}]

\draw (0, 1) -- (10, 1) -- (10, -1) -- (0, -1) -- cycle;
\node (a) at (0, -1) {a};   % south-west corner
\node (b) at (10, 1) {b};   % north-east corner
\node (c) at (5, 0) {c};    % center
\foreach \n in {1,...,50} \draw[gray, very thin]
        ({10/pow(2, \n/12)}, 1)
    --  ({10/pow(2, \n/12)}, -1);

\draw[thick,cyan] (a) to[out=0,in=270,looseness=0.55] (c.center) to[out=65,in=180,looseness=0.5] (b);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: At first I wasn't too keen about using the `to[...]` syntax, but it seems like it's really the easiest way. It pretty much matches what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I get from your description in one of your comments. Was I close to your idea?
If not, perhaps you could provide a hand-drawn mockup.

[image: This?]

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw, circle, fill=white, inner sep=.01cm}]

\draw (0, 1) -- (10, 1) -- (10, -1) -- (0, -1) -- cycle;
\node (a) at (0, -1) {a};   % south-west corner
\node (b) at (10, 1) {b};   % north-east corner
\node (c) at (5, 0) {c};    % center
\foreach \n in {1,...,50} \draw[gray, very thin]
        ({10/pow(2, \n/12)}, 1)
    --  ({10/pow(2, \n/12)}, -1);

\draw[cyan] (a) .. controls +(5, 0) and +(-.5, -.5) .. (c.center) .. controls +(.5,.5) and +(-1,0) .. (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, too bad I can't accept two correct answers - yours seems to be a good alternative to what Harish Kumar posted.

Comment: Not worry about the acceptance. More important to me is, if I got it right. Was this the kind of slope you wanted?

Comment: Yes, this is the kind of slope that I wanted. Your answer made me understand how `controls` really works. Harish Kumar's answer just seemed simpler to me, but both are correct.